# Replace using VIM, reuse part of the search pattern

Tags: vim, regular-expression, vi, replace

I am working with `VIm` and trying to set up a search and replace command to do some replacements where I can re-use the regular expression that is part of my search string.

A simple example would be a line where I want to replace `(10)` to `{10}`, where 10 can be any number.

I came this far

```
  .s/([0-9]*)/what here??/
```

which matches exactly the part that I want.

Now the replacement, I tried

```
  .s/([0-9]*)/{\0}/
```

But, this gives as output `{(10)}`

Then, I tried

```
 .s/(\zs[0-9]*\ze)/{\0}/
```

However, that gave me `({10})`, which I also close, but not what I want.

I think I need some other kind of marking/back-referencing instead of this `\0`, but I don't know where to look. So the question is, can this be done in vim, and if so, how?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`\0` is the whole match. To use only part of it you need to set it like this and use \1

```
.s/(\([0-9]*\))/{\1}/
```

More detailed instruction you can find [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace#Details) or in vim help.

Comment: Note the parentheses for the capture are backslash-escaped.

Answer (score 4):

I recently inherited some legacy code and I wanted to replace all occurrences
like:

```
print "xx"
print x,y
print 'xx'
```

to

```
logging.info("xy")
```

or

```
logging.info(x,y)
```

***Building on the previous answer*** and in hopes that someone will benefit from it
I used the following command, that will change all occurrences:

```
%s/print\( .*\)/logging.info\(\1\)/g
```

If you substitute `%` with `.` and remove `/g` you will end  up
with

```
.s/print\( .*\)/logging.info\(\1\)
```

that will enable you to go over each match and choose whether you change it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to enable you to go over each match is to add a "c" to the end of the code, rather than go line-by-line

```
%s/print\( .*\)/logging.info\(\1\)/gc
```

Comment: This really doesn't answer the original question in any way

Comment: Would be a good comment. Regardless, it's presence is appreciated.